# SWIFT : Update Value NSDictionary

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

NSDictionary in this example :

```
var example: [Int:AnyObject] = [1:["A":"val","B":[1:["B1":"val"]]]]
```

how to update "B1" value OR should i not use NSDictionary for this complex value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest either of the following two options, but not a mix:

1. Find a way to structure you data, so you can use the power of the Swift `Dictionary` class.
2. Use a `NSDictionary` and ignore Swift's awesomeness.

Almost needless to say: It's so much better to go for the first option, if your data allows it. Using `AnyObject`s in a `Dictionary` isn't a good way. Note that you could also use `struct`s to structure your data.

Comment: Why AnyObject in Dictionary isn't good way ? can i do this : var example : [Int:AnyObject] = [1:class()]

Comment: Code safe, do it the Swift way! In Swift you have explicitly typed collections, which lead to more code safety and less bugs. Instead of guessing the type, it's compiler-enforced. Makes your life a lot easier in the end!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update this structure at all, because it implicitly has an immutable type. As a test:

```
var example: [Int: AnyObject] = [1:["A":"val","B":[1:["B1":"val"]]]]

if let dict=example[1] as? NSMutableDictionary {
    "Mutable dictionary"
} else if let dict=example[1] as? NSDictionary {
    "Immutable dictionary" // < THIS will be printed as a result
} else {
    "Other"
}
```

Your model is pretty confusing - I would recommend classes/types that wrap your data and give you a better idea of what you're dealing with at each level.

It *is* possible to create this structure in such a way that the layered dictionaries are mutable, but it's a pain, and neither easy to read nor deal with.